# How can one view the create table DDL for a bigquery table?

Tags: google-bigquery, ddl

I'm trying to use the Web UI to extract a create table statement, so that I can see how one might create a nullable repeated column (if possible).

I've managed to make something like that using a query is some context.  It created a record column with a mode repeated, which within it had a record column with a mode of nullable.  Not sure if that's necessary, and, in any event, I'd like to see how one would go about doing that.

Answer (score 1):

> how one might create a nullable repeated column (if possible)?

below is example of schema to use

```
[
  {
    "name": "myCol",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "myNestedCol",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Same with DDL:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.table`
(
 myCol ARRAY<STRUCT<myNestedCol STRING>>
)
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.table`
(
 myCol ARRAY<STRUCT<myNestedCol STRING>>
)

Comment: I've created a table with the equivalent of this structure:

CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.table`
(
col1 int,
 myCol ARRAY<STRUCT<myNestedCol STRING>>
)

But when I try loading data for with myCol has no entries, the load barfs with the error: "Only optional fiedls can be set to NULL."

Comment: I've tested Mikhail Berlyant's answer and it works for me. Please consider ask another question to keep this one clean, as your question (*how one might create a nullable repeated column (if possible)?*) was solved.